# How to generate synthetic data to train a given logistic regression model in tensorflow probability?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, tensorflow-probability

I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to generate synthetic training data for a classification problem. In particular, I need to generate n data points using [tensorflow_probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/), then use it to train a logistic regression model using scikit-learn.

I've included some sample code below where I implement this procedure. I am wondering: how I can change this code so that the coefficients of the logistic regression model that I will be close to a user-defined coefficient vector? In particular, I'd like users to specify a coefficient vector `W` and ensure that the coefficients of the logistic regression model I fit will be close to `W`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

W = np.array([-5.0, 10.0, 10.0]) #user-defined coefficient vector (W[0] is intercept)
n = 1e6 # number of data points in sample

# specify data distribution
dist = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
        model = [tfd.Bernoulli(probs = 0.5, name = 'x1'),
                 tfd.Bernoulli(probs = 0.5, name = 'x2'),
                 lambda x2, x1: tfd.Bernoulli(logits = W[0] + W[1] * np.array(x1, dtype = np.float) + W[2] * np.array(x2, dtype = np.float), name = 'y')]
        )

# sample n points distribution
values = dist.sample(n, seed = 1337)
df = pd.DataFrame({n.name:v.numpy() for n, v in zip(dist.submodules, values)})

# fit logistic regression classifier
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state = 1337)
clf.fit(X = df[['x1', 'x2']], y = df[['y']])

# check that coefficients are close
W_fitted = np.insert(clf.coef_, 0, clf.intercept_)
assert np.isclose(W, W_fitted, atol = 0.01).all()
```

In theory, this should be possible by sampling data points (x,y) from a distribution where where `y ~ Bernouilli(p)` and `p ~ logistic(<W, x>)`. In the code below, I try to do this by setting `logits` argument of [tfd.Bernoulli](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Bernoulli). The assertion in the code above fails when `W = np.array([-5.0, 10.0, 10.0])`, but it works if I set `W = np.array([-1.0, 1.0, 1.0])`.